# Spring Boot + Spring Security + Spring Rest Issue: 'Access Denied' error

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I created a Spring Boot application from the Spring initializer, included no dependencies at all. 
Then I imported this application into STS-4.4.2. I created a rest controller and added a single POST method. My controller class is below:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app-api/tests")
public class AppApiController {

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String returnTestString(@RequestBody String testString) {
        return "bla bla bla";
    }

}
```

Using Postman, the POST method is executed, and the string message 'bla bla bla' is printed out successfully in the response.

Now I added Spring Security library, and did no further modifications to the application whatsoever.

Re-testing from Postman now does not return anything. I raised the log level to 'DEBUG' and obtained the following:

```
 Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) [spring-web-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) [spring-web-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:206) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) [spring-web-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) [spring-web-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) [spring-web-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_141]
```

- On Postman, I tried to add authorization information as Basic Authorization, used 'user' username and password printed on the console:

  Using generated security password: 6fc537b1-a9ad-439b-8d96-a75f8b49f6d2

With the same result.

Any hints on what could possibly be done to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

When you add the starter security library, authentication gets enabled for the Application.

The password changes for each application restarts and can be found in console log. Below is format:

```
Using default security password: 78fa095d-3f4c-48b1-ad50-e24c31d5cf35
```

Set below properties in application.properties file

```
spring.security.user.name = root
spring.security.user.password = the default password in console log
```

To add your own layer of application security in front of the defaults,

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Now you can use the new credentials:

```
spring.security.user.name = user
spring.security.user.password = password
```

Answer (score 0):

### Spring Security

One common problem with Spring Security is to get a **HTTP 403 Forbidden** when performing a **POST**.

This is referenced in the Spring Security FAQ [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix.html#appendix-faq-forbidden-csrf),  saying :

> **I get a 403 Forbidden when performing a POST**
>
> If an HTTP 403 Forbidden
>   is returned for HTTP POST, but works for HTTP GET then the issue is
>   most likely related to CSRF. Either provide the CSRF Token or disable
>   CSRF protection (not recommended).

This is because CSRF is enabled by default.
See also [CSRF in Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf).
The default with a servlet configuration is to write to a cookie named **XSRF-TOKEN** and read it from a header named **X-XSRF-TOKEN** or the HTTP parameter **_csrf** (see class `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository`).

### Spring Boot

Spring Boot autoconfigures the security when Spring Security is found on classpath.
See [Security in Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-security).

See how it is auto-configured in Spring Boot : [SecurityAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SecurityAutoConfiguration.java)